SWD scan failing for STM32H747 using a BlackMagicProbev2.3
I'm trying to debug an Arduino R1 Giga WiFi board with a STM32H747XIH6 mcu, which is a dual-core ARM Cortex-M4 and Cortex-M7 chip, using a Black Magic Probe v2.3 (BMP) from 1bitSquared. I've managed to communicate with my BMP through gdb-multiarch, however when sending mon swd_scan it always return that the scan has failed. I've tried updating the firmware and reducing the SWJ frequency but none of the two solved my issue.
The BMP is connected to the target board through a ribbon cable into a JTAG Pin Header.


Using a JTAG scan is not an option since the board hardware configuration only allows me to use SWD.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Do you know if the processor is "locked"? Have you tried asking for help in the #blackmagic channel of the 1BitSquared Discord?

@Attie Not yet, I'll try asking there. Thanks for the suggestion!
Also, when you say "locked" you mean in a hard-fault state? I previously flashed (with a j-link) a LED Flasher code so it was very simple code and it was working fine.

By "locked", I was really referring to things like readout protection, SWD disabled, etc...

@Attie, After further investigating turns out my board was missing a bootloader.  I followed some forums at arduino and managed to burn the bootloader again on my board. The LED flasher that I previously executed as soon as I plugged the power on my board and I was able to run a swd_scan. Unfortunately I do not remember how I managed to erase the bootloader from my board.

I'm a little surprised you need a bootloader if you're using SWD... but glad you got it working!

@Attie It really leaves us with a lot of questions, I was surprised as well that flashing a bootloader fixed my issue. It seems to me that the board was somehow stuck/locked in a state where not even shaking the SWD pins would throw it out. But I can't put my finger exactly on what...

After further investigating the issue it turns out that flashing arduino bootloader for r1 giga WiFi is what enabled me to debug the board. The main reason is that the firmware that was previously flashed had a MPU_Config (generated automatically through CubeMX tool) function call to configure the MPU Unit for CM7 core, thus raising the read protection level and therefore blocking me from running a swd_scan. To set my board in a DFU mode I had to press and hold BOOT0 button and then plug my board to my computer and then detected it using STM32CubeProgrammer through USB connection.

Please could you expand on how you flashed the bootloader (I'm guessing not via SWD?)

@attie, I used the USB-C on the board. Pressed and held the BOOT0 push-button (bottom right button from the picture I posted) and connected my board to my PC. The device appeared as "DFU in FS mode" and then I managed to detect it using STM32CubeProgrammer and flashed the bootloader file arduino provided.
In addition to that, after playing around with the board, I believe your suspicion of the board being locked was correct. I noticed that CubeIDE generates code for the CM7 Core MPU unit, which would exlpain why I wasn't being able to detect the board via swd_scan

Thanks for the info - glad you got it working!
